# How to create WordPress application password without loading wordpress core files?

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, hash

I am using Laravel 10 to build a CMS manager to remotely manage multiple CMS at single panel. One of the CMS available is WordPress. Most API functions works well such as publishing posts, creating tags, etc. All I need to do is to create an application password manually and paste to my Laravel CMS manager.

As I can also access the mysql of the WordPress sites, I would like to create the application password programmatically via Laravel instead of manually at WordPress dashboard. My thought is first create a hashed password and save directly to database `wp_usermeta` table.

**However, the programmatically generated password seems not correct. WordPress return 401.**

The following is how I generate the application password.

As WordPress uses `WP_Application_Passwords::create_new_application_password()` to generate the password which the hashing of `$new_password` is done by `wp_hash_password($new_password)`, so I load `PasswordHash` in my Laravel CMS manager.

```
function wp_hash_password($password) {
    $wp_hasher = new \PasswordHash( 8, TRUE );
    $hashed_password = $wp_hasher->HashPassword(trim($password));
    return $hashed_password;
}
```

Then I prepare the format for `wp_usermeta`.

```
$api_password = 'kNRC ERNk ZJJ4 nrL2 EgKI HctJ'; //also tried without space
$this->wp_hash_password($api_password)
$api_password_data_array[] = [
    'uuid' => str()->uuid()->toString(), //6890ea8f-e7c9-4ab0-b51a-c2a3d724eecc
    'app_id' => '',
    "name" => "ai2",
    "password" => $hashed_password, //$P$Bl7AWybOsI3/JJIHpvv/rf1JrwZeeK0
    "created" => time(),
    'last_used' => null,
    'last_ip'   => null,
];

//Connect remote wordpress database.
DB::connection($connection_name)
->table('wp_usermeta')
->updateOrInsert(
    [
        'meta_key' => '_application_passwords'
    ],
    [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'meta_value' => serialize($api_password_data_array)
    ]
);
```

The programmatically generated data structure created is exactly the same as when I manually create application password via wordpress dashboard.

```
a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:4:"uuid";s:36:"6890ea8f-e7c9-4ab0-b51a-c2a3d724eecc";s:6:"app_id";s:0:"";s:4:"name";s:3:"ai2";s:8:"password";s:34:"$P$Bl7AWybOsI3/JJIHpvv/rf1JrwZeeK0";s:7:"created";i:1708716939;s:9:"last_used";N;s:7:"last_ip";N;}}
```

However, It's just not working. WordPress always return 401.

Therefore, my question is:

**How to create WordPress application password and directly save to database without requiring the wordpress files?**

Comment: Is the network option the original method sets, to indicate that application passwords are in use, set already in your WP? https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/wp-includes/class-wp-application-passwords.php#L122